# Using an SVG and be able to click and highlight the part?

Tags: c#, forms, image, svg

I am using forms application to import a SVG to a picture box and I am trying to find if it is possible to click a certain part/section of the SVG to highlight the clicked "segment".

If not possible in forms, is it possible with asp.net?

Update:
I follow the example on this site: https://www.codementor.io/@lasithapetthawadu/using-vector-svg-graphics-in-c-net-k9y1ybc8a
the sample code is in a download link on that site.

Thanks in advance

Beest, Marcus

Comment: I feel your question is ok enough and is a do you know if. Please for the sake of **making things easier for us post some code**. Some people will want to try and solve your problem but are not experienced with winforms and SVG but are experienceed programmers..https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is waaay to broad.

Comment: @TaW how? He asks about winforms picture box and svg.Specifically how to make the svg to click on a certain segment. I think the only thing missing from this question is an exampe. In html this is very easy to achieve because of how you can structure the svg. In no case this is broad.

Comment: @panoskarajohn so html seems to be easier to do this in? eventhough my SVG is a schematic of hardware with wires that I want to click and highlight?

Comment: @MarcusBorén svg in html is out of scope in this question.